# Replace title when hovering the image in WooCommerce single Products

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to replace the product title in WooCommerce when hovering **the product image**, but not the title itself. I would appreciate anyone's advice as I cannot find any answer that relates to my question.

Tried using CSS `:hover`, `::after` and `::after:hover`, but I can't change the product title text because the hover action is actually related to the image and not the title. So I am stuck and not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated *(code improvement: enable the feature in product shortcode and blocks)*

For WooCommerce single product pages, you can use the following to change the product title, when "hovering" the product image:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'single_product_script_js' );
function single_product_script_js() {
    // Here set the text replacement for the product title
    $text = __("Text replacement", "woocommerce");
    
    wc_enqueue_js("const productTitle  = $('.product_title').html(), textReplacement = '{$text}';
    $('body').on('mouseover mouseout', '.woocommerce-product-gallery__image', function(e) {
        $('.product_title').html(e.type === 'mouseover' ? textReplacement : productTitle);
    });");
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

---

Initial answer code:

```php
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_footer_product_script_js' );
function wp_footer_product_script_js() {
    if( is_product() ) :
    // Here set the text replacement for the product title
    $text = __("Text replacement", "woocommerce");
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        const productTitle  = $('.product_title').html(),    
            textReplacement = '<?php echo $text; ?>';
        $('body').on('mouseover mouseout', '.woocommerce-product-gallery__image', function(e) {
            $('.product_title').html(e.type === 'mouseover' ? textReplacement : productTitle);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It works. No need to expand this currently for the multiproduct case scenario.

Comment: @tecne Update: I have just improved the code in a better way.

Answer (score -2):

To replace the product title in WooCommerce when hovering over the product image, you can use CSS to target the product title element and change its content on hover. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```css
/* Replace product title on hover */
.product:hover .product-title {
  content: "Your New Title Here";
  /* Additional styling for the replaced title */
  color: #FF0000; /* Change text color */
  font-weight: bold; /* Make it bold */
  /* Add any other styling you desire */
}
```

In this example, replace `.product-title` with the actual CSS class or selector that targets the product title element in your WooCommerce theme. Make sure to specify the desired content, and you can also add additional styling as needed.

Remember to adjust the CSS to match your specific WooCommerce theme's structure and classes. Additionally, it's important to test and make adjustments as necessary to achieve the desired hover effect.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I will go with the 1st proposed solution. Highly appreciated your effort.